# Creating a snowflake schema in talend

Tags: database, talend, data-warehouse, snowflake-schema, data-quality

I'm discovering **Talend Data Quality Dashboards** through a tutorial, and i want to create a schema as shown below but i cant find how:

[image]

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @NickW i'm using oracle